# parallel openMP loop in cpp

Tags: c++, openmp, parallel.for

I am trying to learn parallelization with openMP in cpp. I am using the following test example

```
 #pragma parallel for num_threads( 4 )
 for ( int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ ){
     for ( int j = 0 ; j < 100000 ; j++ ){
         data[ i ]  =  data[ i ] + ( double ) i ;
     } 
 }
```

I am using 4 threads; with top ( in unix ) I should see then in the col %CPU
400% or something similar. But I get 100% what would be the case for serial execution.
And if I measure the time there is no velocity gain compared to serial execution. I can not figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you use the compiler flag `-fopenmp`?

Comment: Yes I did, this should not be the problem then. Binding the openmp libraries is working because I checked this already with the function giving thread number.

Comment: I timed the code with cpp ctime library clock() but also with an external bash timer that is independent of the executed cpp code and returns real time. And if parallelism is working I should see a number higher than 100% in the cpu usage. Or am I missing something. The values for N=100,10000,100000.     Yes and the results are only printed later to see if the sum is correct what is the case. It should be only an example for a more complicated loop that I want to parallelize

Comment: No this question has a different issue since my code is not speeding up at all and my cpu usage stays at 100%. I also tried now compiling with -O0 what should remove all optimizations because you argued the compiler optimization but without luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `omp` in the `pragma` directive.

Try:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads( 4 )
```

As described [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/32-openmp-traps-for-c-developers/#IDAPMQDC), this is one of the most common mistakes when using OpenMP in C++.

With the GCC compiler it is possible to catch this problem by compiling with the `-Wall` or `-Wunknown pragmas` flag. It's a good habit to use `-Wall` as it preempts many otherwise mysterious issues. Other compilers have similar options.

Comment: (Added note about the `-Wall` flag, &c.)