# Parallelize filling of Eigen Matrix in C++

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, eigen

Let's say that i am trying to fill a MatrixXf with the rolling mean of another MatrixXf like this

```
MatrixXf ComputeRollingMean(const MatrixXf& features) {
    MatrixXf df(features.rows() - 30, features.cols());

    for (size_t i = 30; i < features.rows(); ++i) {
            MatrixXf mat = features.block(i-30, 0, 30, 3);
            RowVectorXf mean_vector = mat.colwise().mean();
            RowVectorXf stdev_vector = ((mat.rowwise() - mean_vector).colwise().squaredNorm() / (mat.rows()-1)).cwiseSqrt();
            MatrixXf zscores = (mat.rowwise() - mean_vector).array().rowwise() / stdev_vector.array();
            RowVectorXf zscore = zscores(last, all);
            df.block(index, 0, 1, 3) = zscore;
    }
    return df;
}
```

It seems that Eigen has some sort of parallelism process

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
```

and then

```
int main() {
    Eigen::initParallel();
    ...}
```

But I am not sure how this can parallelize the for loop in my ComputeRollingMean function. Anyone knows how I could parallelize, and maybe choose the number of process i want to start please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [parallel openMP loop in cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965978/parallel-openmp-loop-in-cpp)

Comment: But isn't it betetr to use the eigen function for this though?

Comment: read the part where it says `Currently, the following algorithms can make use of multi-threading:` [Make Eigen run in parallel](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html)

Comment: I do not advise you to use the Eigen parallelism, nor any similar library API (e.g. C++ ones) unless you care more about having a simple program rather than an efficient one. The reason is that such operation is likely memory bound so cache matters a lot and parallelizing separate functions can never be more efficient than parallelizing the loop yourself. Often the data distribution is not stable between function increasing the memory pressure which is very precious. Eigen may merge operations but it is not always simple nor possible for Eigen (while you can often do better manually)

Comment: Besides doing a rolling mean using a loop of classical mean is not efficient (assuming I understood the code correctly). You can write your own rolling mean which can just *iterate on every item only once*. This makes the problem completely memory-bound then on all mainstream machines. Few threads are often enough to saturate the DRAM bandwidth (1~2 on PCs, 3~6 on most servers per socket). It is better to avoid storing big matrices.

Comment: Your implementation is not well optimized. You should not start parallelizing before you have exhausted reasonable improvements to the serial version, e.g. getting rid of that dynamic allocation of `RowVectorXf` inside the loop. Even if you don't want to implement an efficient rolling mean, you should realize that this is just a convolution. So you could just throw a parallelized image or signal processing library at the problem

Comment: Can you elaborate please ? ^^ I am trying to optimize cause I have 100 files  to analyze and 1 takes more than 12h... here I simplified but in reality I am trying to compute a rolling zscore by column

Comment: If you want a rolling mean of `n` samples, you can compute the next mean value from the previous one by subtracting the `value[i - 1] / n` that "falls out of the window" and add the `value[i + n - 1] / n` that "moves into the window." We should start looking for a similar recurrence for your z score. Please edit your question to include the actual formula (doesn't need to be the full code for me, just the actual definition). Also, the real size of the matrix and the true window size if the 30 above was just an example.

Comment: I've updated with my actual code to compute my rolling zscore